# How to find equal relation between two values

Tags: coq

I have less or equal relation between two values.Then how I can convert this relation into equal relation. Here is code

```
Theorem  find_value :forall (n : nat)(l : list nat),
  (value 0 0 (n :: l) <=? n) = true -> 
  (value 0 0 (n :: l) = n).
```

This is only possible, when`((length l =? 0) = true` means `(n::nil)`.
But in hypothesis I have

```
(length l =? 0) = false
```

Comment: Please consider reformulating the question.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and in particular https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. Here are a few clarifications you can make to help us understand better what's going on: (1) what does `value` mean? what is its definition? (2) What did you do in your proof to get to the hypothesis you have?